# How to test if the email is a regular email or reply?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

I am writing a script which will automatically save emails to a specified folder based on date. So basically, all of the emails today, will be saved in a folder marked 05/20/2015.

The problem in which I am currently experiencing is that all reply messages are being saved as a file, rather than **.msg**.

My question is, is there a way to test if the email is a response or a regular email. I figure that I would have been able to do something like this. `If Item.Reply Then (code here)`. Would this be the correct way of doing so, or would I have to go about in testing if the email is a reply is a different way?

Here is the code that I am working with. Here is an example of what I mean. Joe sends me an email. That email gets saved to my specified folder as a .msg. I respond to Joe. Joe responds back. Theoretically the response back from Joe should be saved as .msg, but the message is being saved as .file. That is the part that I do not understanding and I have no idea why this is happening.

```
    Option Explicit
'// Save the message as a native .msg
Public Sub SaveMesg(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
 Dim fso As FileSystemObject
 Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim SavePath As String
 Dim TimeDate As Date
 Dim SaveName As String
 Dim Enviro As String
 Dim NewFolder As String
 Dim EmailSubject As String

'// enviro gets the user account part of the path
'// so you can use the same code on different computers
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

ReplaceCharsForFileName SaveName, "_"

'// Use My Documents for older Windows.
NewFolder = "C:\ITDocs\" & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "\"

'// Test if directory or file exists
If FileOrDirExists(NewFolder) Then
    MsgBox NewFolder & " exists!"
Else
    MkDir NewFolder
End If

EmailSubject = FileName(Item.Subject)

'// Determine if there is subject
If Item.Subject <> vbNullString Then
    EmailSubject = Item.Subject
Else
    EmailSubject = "No Subject"
End If

'// Determine if the email is a response or not
'// If Item.Reply <> vbNullString Then
   '// EmailSubject = Item.Subject
 '//End If


'// Get Email subject & set name to be saved as
TimeDate = Item.ReceivedTime
SaveName = Format(TimeDate, "YYYYMMDD", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
vbUseSystem) & Format(TimeDate, "-HHNNSS", _
vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & EmailSubject & SaveName & ".msg"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")



'// Save .msg File
SavePath = "C:\IT Documents\" & NewFolder & "\"
Debug.Print NewFolder & SaveName
Item.SaveAs NewFolder & SaveName, olMSG

End Sub

'// This function removes invalid and other characters from file names
Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(SaveName As String, _
 sChr As String _
 )
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "/", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "\", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, ":", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "?", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, Chr(34), sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "<", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, ">", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "|", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "&", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "%", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "*", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, " ", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "{", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "[", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "]", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "}", sChr)
 SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "!", sChr)

End Sub

'// Good practice suggests that it is wise to check before taking certain               actions
'// This function checks if File or Dir Exists
Function FileOrDirExists(PathName As String) As Boolean
Dim iTemp As Integer

 '// Ignore errors to allow for error evaluation
On Error Resume Next
iTemp = GetAttr(PathName)

 '// Check if error exists and set response appropriately
Select Case Err.Number
Case Is = 0
    FileOrDirExists = True
Case Else
    FileOrDirExists = False
End Select

 '// Resume error checking
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function FileName(strText As String) As String
 Dim strStripChars As String
 Dim intLen As Integer
 Dim i As Integer
 strStripChars = "/\[]:=," & Chr(34)
    intLen = Len(strStripChars)
 strText = Trim(strText)
    For i = 1 To intLen
 strText = Replace(strText, Mid(strStripChars, i, 1), "")

 Next
 FileName = strText
End Function
```

Comment: Show the code you have now or the relevant sections of it.

Comment: Try uninstalling your outlook-2013 and then do clean installation, that might fix the problem you are having, your receive email should not be saved as dot-file. all outlook email are saved dot.msg.

Comment: or try turn off your add-in and test the code

Comment: @Omar are you talking about turning off all my add-ins?

Comment: Yes it could be something that is messing up ur file format. It's it's unusual that outlook is saving ur emails as .file

Comment: I have tried disabling all of my add-ins and the problem still persists. The only thing I have not done yet is uninstall and reinstall office. I will give that a shot this weekend and will let you know if that solved my issues or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You note that the problem happens when you encounter a message which is either a reply or a forward. One thing both of those have in common is a prefix on the subject, like "RE: something" or "FW: something else". Note the colon in the prefix. I don't see you doing any work to scrub that colon out of the name before calling SaveAs. So you'd be giving SaveAs a pretty odd path with multiple colons in it.

I don't know how SaveAs would react to that, but I'd start there.

Comment: I am doing so with the Sub Routine that I created. That Sub is being called after I set the namespace. In that Sub, I have it set to replace the colon

Comment: If you're speaking of `ReplaceCharsForFileName`, you're calling it when SaveName is still an empty string, but not later after you've set SaveName to a string derived from the subject. You needs to call is some time after the `SaveName = Format` line.

Comment: Wow, I was completely blind. That did it. Thank you very much for your help. That was killing me

Answer (score 2):

The [PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415575.aspx) low-level property contains a bitmask of flags indicating the origin and current state of a message. You are interested in the following flags:

- MSGFLAG_READ

The message is marked as having been read. Clients can set this flag by calling a message's IMAPIProp::SetProps method before the message has been saved for the first time. This flag is ignored if the MSGFLAG_ASSOCIATED flag is set.

- MSGFLAG_UNSENT

The message is still being composed. It is saved, but has not been sent. Typically, this flag is cleared after the message is sent.

You can use the [PropertyAccessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176395%28office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) object to get the low-level property value. DASL name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E070003`.

Use any low-level property viewer such as MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy for exploring such properties and their values.

Comment: I don't believe that I would need to use the msgflags. What happens is all responses and forwards get saved as a .file extension rather than .msg. My plan is to find a way to check that the email that is coming in is a reply, forward, original email then save as .msg. The original email saves fine, but not replies or forwards. Those are all being saved as .file.

Answer (score 1):

What is your definition of "regular email"? Do you mean you need to distinguish whether a message was **sent** by the current user or **received**?

Received messages have the MailItem.ReceivedByName populated. Sent messages do not.

Comment: Regular mail I mean when the new message first arrives. Example, I receive an email from Joe for the very first time.

Comment: You may find the PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED (0x10810003) property helpful. The DASL name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003`. Use the PropertyAccessor object for getting the value.

Comment: Do you mean a message that is not a reply to your original message? You can check if PR_IN_REPLY_TO_ID (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1042001F`) is set - it corresponds to the In-Reply-To MIME header which you can see in the PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS property. Take a look at a message with OutlookSpy (click IMessage) to see if these properties are present in your case and have the expected values.

Comment: I guess basically my thought process for this right now is since that ALL replies and forwards are being saved as a .file, I figure lets run this through an IF statement. My thoughts is that the IF statement will check if the message is a reply or forward, and if it is, save it as a message. That is the only other thing I can think of to possibly prevent all of the email messages that are a reply or a forward to be saved properly.